# Python Debugging, Program will not display text lines outside user input of 1

Tags: python, python-3.7

The basics of the program are to ask the user for a .txt file and count how many lines in the file. Then the program displays the number of lines in the file and the user will input a number to display a certain line in the file. If the user hits 0 the program will end.

The program runs fine until I enter a number besides 1 or the last line number in the .txt file. The program proceeds to display the "Enter a line number, want to quit? Hit 0" Over and over.

```
inName = input("Enter the a valid file name: ")
inputFile = open(inName, "r")
count = 0
for line in inputFile:
    count = count + 1
print("The file has " + str(count) + " lines.")
inputFile.close()

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter a line number, want to quit? Hit 0: "))
        lineno = 0
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Try again. Line number must be between 1 and " + str(count))

while n != 0:
    if n >= 0 and n <= count:
        inputFile = open(inName, "r")
        for line in inputFile:
            lineno = lineno + 1
            if lineno == n:
                print(line)
                inputFile.close()
            else:
                print("Try again. Line number must be between 1 and " + str(count))

            while True:
                try:
                    n = int(input("Enter a line number, hit 0 to quit: "))
                    lineno = 0
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Try again. Line number must be between 1 and " + str(count))
```

Comment: This code is spaghetti, you're closing the file in the middle of the loop without breaking, and why's `lineno` first initialized  in a completely irrelevant scope? consider using `with open()` instead of manually managing the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not address the multitude of issues with your code, since the comments and answer have done a pretty thorough job there already. Instead, I'd like to discuss the I/O problem you are creating by opening and closing the file over and over. It's expensive to do that. For a program that spends virtually all its time waiting for user input, is probably won't be noticeable, but opening and closing files without need is a bad habit.

I would suggest one of two solutions to get around this. If you are dealing with small text files, just load the whole thing into memory, e.g. with `file.readlines()`:

```
inName = input("Enter the a valid file name: ")
with open(inName, "r") as file:
    data = file.readlines()
count = len(data)
print(f"The file has {count} lines.")

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter a line number, want to quit? Hit 0: "))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Try again. Line number must be between 1 and {count}")
    else:
        if n == 0:
            break
        print(data[n - 1])
```

For large files, I would agree with your technique of loading only one line at a time, but you have to be smart about it. I would open the file once, create a table of offsets to the line starts, and move around the file using that table:

```
inName = input("Enter the a valid file name: ")
with open(inName, "r") as file:
    table = [0]
    table.extend(file.tell() for _ in file)
    count = len(table) - 1  # last entry is size of file
    print(f"The file has {count} lines.")

    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("Enter a line number, want to quit? Hit 0: "))
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Try again. Line number must be between 1 and {count}")
        else:
            if n == 0:
                break
            file.seek(table[n - 1])
            print(file.readline()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Refactored your code and made some changes in the loops, removed the part where you were closing the file mid-loop and replaced it with break.

Try this if it works :

```
inName = input("Enter the a valid file name: ")
inputFile = open(inName,"r")
count = 0
for line in inputFile:
    count = count + 1

print("The file has "+str(count)+" lines.");
inputFile.close()

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter a line number, want to quit? Hit 0: "))
        lineno = 0

    except ValueError:
        print("Try again. Line number must be between 1 and "+str(count))

    if n != 0:
        if n >= 0 and n <= count:
            inputFile = open(inName, "r")
            for line in inputFile:

                if lineno == n:
                    print(line)
                    #inputFile.close()
                    break
                else:
                    lineno = lineno + 1
        else:
            print("Try again. Line number must be between 1 and "+str(count))


    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!